# How to identify a particular pattern exists in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i am new to programming and i would like to find if a particular pattern exists in a string.

I have a string `"i am [1234@some data] some data given to [223@123some data]"`

I want to check if the string contains pattern like `[1234@some data]` or `[223@123some data]` is present. So it includes square-bracket followed by one or more digits followed by one @ character followed by zero or more digits followed by one or more alphabets followed by space and one or more alphabets.

What i have tried?

```
const string = "i am [1234@some data] some data given to [223@123some data]"
const pattern_present = string.match((/^\d+\@+\w+$/)
```

This doesnt seem to work. Could someone help me with this

Comment: Why `^` and `$`? Use `\[` and `]` instead. Use `/\[(\d+@[\w\s]+)]/g`. You may as well use `/\[([^\][]*)]/g` to get all strings inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\[(\d+@[\w\s]+)]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jq3pfh/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5B(%5Cd%2B%40%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B)%5D):

[image]

Note you may match any chars but `[` and `]` after `@`:

```
/\[(\d+@[^\][]+)]/g
        ^^^^^^
```

JS demo:

```js
const string = "i am [1234@some data] some data given to [223@123some data]"
let matches = [...string.matchAll(/\[(\d+@[\w\s]+)]/g)];
console.log(Array.from(matches, m => m[0])); // Full matches with square brackets
console.log(Array.from(matches, m => m[1])); // Captures only without square brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\[[0-9]{1,}@[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}\s[a-zA-Z]{1,})
```

so:

- square-bracket is a reserved character so we use escape char \ to refer to it like a simple cahr
- [0-9] it's a pattern of a digit from 0 to 9.
- {1,} this is the number of appearance of what you are searching so: [0-9]{1,} means 1 digit or more.
- @ is the character that you are looking
- [0-9a-zA-Z]{1,} : any appearance of digits or characters
- \s : that is for space
- [a-zA-Z]{1,} : any appearance of characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
/\[\d+@\d*[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\]/g
```

Comment: Why use `mi`? They are not useful with your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For example - /[\d+@.+?]/mg
For matching a few substrings you should  add flag "g" and for multiline search "m"